# paypal parallel and express checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm using the new version of paypal Checkout Express API to impliment the parallel payment,

When i send the request I got an error:

```
The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
```

This is the request and response from api debug:

```
INFO: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"><soapenv:Header><urn:RequesterCredentials><ebl:Credentials><ebl:Username>sdk-three_api1.sdk.com</ebl:Username><ebl:Password>QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q</ebl:Password><ebl:Signature>A-IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU</ebl:Signature></ebl:Credentials></urn:RequesterCredentials></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><urn:SetExpressCheckoutReq><urn:SetExpressCheckoutRequest><ebl:Version>92.0</ebl:Version><ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails><ebl:ReturnURL>http://localhost:8080/EC/GetExpressCheckout?currencyCodeType=null</ebl:ReturnURL><ebl:CancelURL>http://localhost:8080/index.html</ebl:CancelURL><ebl:NoShipping>0</ebl:NoShipping><ebl:PaymentDetails><ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">10.00</ebl:OrderTotal><ebl:ItemTotal currencyID="USD">10.0</ebl:ItemTotal><ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity><ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">10.0</ebl:Amount></ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity><ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">10.0</ebl:Amount></ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:SellerDetails><ebl:PayPalAccountID>tarik._1341024461_biz@gmail.com</ebl:PayPalAccountID></ebl:SellerDetails><ebl:PaymentAction>Sale</ebl:PaymentAction><ebl:PaymentRequestID>1</ebl:PaymentRequestID></ebl:PaymentDetails><ebl:PaymentDetails><ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">10.00</ebl:OrderTotal><ebl:ItemTotal currencyID="USD">10.0</ebl:ItemTotal><ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity><ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">10.0</ebl:Amount></ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity><ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">10.0</ebl:Amount></ebl:PaymentDetailsItem><ebl:SellerDetails><ebl:PayPalAccountID> tarik._1341024461_biz@gmail.com</ebl:PayPalAccountID></ebl:SellerDetails><ebl:PaymentAction>Sale</ebl:PaymentAction><ebl:PaymentRequestID>2</ebl:PaymentRequestID></ebl:PaymentDetails></ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails></urn:SetExpressCheckoutRequest></urn:SetExpressCheckoutReq></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

9 août 2012 01:01:34 com.paypal.core.LoggingManager log
INFO: 2012-08-08T23:01:33ZFailure222642713a617Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.10413Error92.03386080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is what it says:

```
The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.#
```

Make sure you are sending the same amount of items from the cart to match the order amount.